# Pandas dtype('O') to Date format

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, transformation

I believe I have tried every answer I could find on this page. The problem I am still having is converting a column to date format, and deleting the time from it.

[image]

This is my data frame, **mixed datetimes and integers in passed array** is the error I am getting with most of the methods I tried. I also failed converting it to a string -> date. Not sure how to approach this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have a look on:  https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way you can convert to date and can also add other conditions

```
    import datetime
    def convert_to_date(x):
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(x , '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    
    df.loc[:, 'Date'] = df['Date'].apply(convert_to_date)
    
    # better to use a lambda function

    df.loc[:, 'Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x:datetime.datetime.strptime(x , '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Comment: I am getting a KeyError: 'Date'

Comment: From the data frame, I can see you are using 'Date' as a column name just change the date to Date

Comment: change the 'date' to 'Date'? I am using 'Date' as the name of the column and the name of the variable in the code